# Attack from anonymous proxy

Tags: security, spam

We got attacked by some very-bored teenagers registering in our forums and posting very explicit material using anonymous proxy websites, like http://proxify.com/

Is there a way to check the registration IP against a black list database?  Has anyone experienced this and had success?

---

Sorry, it didn't link my account from StackOverflow to here :(

Anyway, I used Proxify.com and got an IP of 67.15.76.115, unfortunately, Spamhaus doesn't list that IP?

Comment: And you know these are bored teenagers because...?

Answer (score 1):

[ not tested, just some thoughts ]:

what you can try to do is to check ips of posters against couple of rbl servers [ just as it is done with e-mail ]. list of some rbls that can help you: http://spamlinks.net/filter-dnsbl-lists.htm#proxies. problem is such approach will introduce significant delay and degrade user experience. you can combine it together with local geoip database [ eg from [maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country) ] and apply the check only to those who are coming from 'suspicious' directions.

there are also paid services that will keep updated list of proxies - eg [killabot](http://www.killabot.net/). if you are willing to pay there should be no problem with modifying their wordpress protection script and using for your website.

Comment: Its only a matter of time before you are hacked though Wordpress.

Comment: @The Rook - well - i'm talking about using this mechanizm with whatever custom application mmgn has. nothing more nothing less; besides i believe if you keep things updated [ both your php ecosystem and the blog engine itself ] - you are pretty safe. sure - if you lag behind you will get owned sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Many proxies are tracked by the [Spamhaus](http://www.spamhaus.org/) project.   Specifically the SBL and XBL should be used for this purpose. You can use [Squid](http://www.frws.com/squid_block/) to deny hosts that are on these black lists.

There are also [for pay services](http://www.fraudlabs.com/freelicense.aspx?PackageID=3).  And you could even check the "x-forwarded-for" header,  but "anonymous proxies" wont' set this variable.  Further more this is an attacker controlled variable and can never really be trusted.